# Change jstree small triangles icons when open and close nodes

Tags: javascript, css, jstree

I'm trying to change the small triangle icon in the jstree (https://www.jstree.com/)

I found this code :

```
.on('open_node.jstree', function (e, data) { data.instance.set_icon(data.node, "glyphicon glyphicon-minus"); 
.on('close_node.jstree', function (e, data) { data.instance.set_icon(data.node, "glyphicon glyphicon-plus"); });
```

But this changes the main icon. I just want to change the small triangle icons into plus and minus instead the default "white" and "black" triangles.

I've tried so many things but nothing helped me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see by inspecting the tree, the images are actually a unique image, handled with background-position.

[image]

To be able to customize the arrow icon you should edit the theme image with an image editor, and replace the arrows with the icon you prefer

Comment: When you add image, Please make sure that it is visible in the post instead of link. Thanks.

Comment: I know. They are using a sprite sheet but i cant find this spritesheet. its somewhere on their server and i'm using their css through cdn. Because if  i make a css file from their cdn i dont have the spritesheet.

Comment: @user3027778 I believe you can't do that by loading they're cdn files, you should use a local copy to be able to replace that image. Or you'll have to have a CSS that overwrites all the background-images with your own one.

Comment: I will just use your image. I took the css code and reformated it into my webstorm so now i have the css locally and changed the image now just have to change the icons with mine.